# index & Match excel

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa3B7.jpg)

[image]

Hello

Please I need help for below schedule, in cell E13 it should be Factory name Transport-ER, but because the Column F for labor Maint. Charge cell F12 is same as F13 it gives result in Cell E13 the same name of E12.

My question: if you could help me how to solve the problem in E13 to become Transport-ER

Thanks

Comment: Show data of `B` and `D` column of your specified range.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula and let us know your feedback.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$50:$B$184,MATCH(F12,$D$50:$D$184,0)+COUNTIF($F$12:$F12,F12)-1),"")
```

Comment: It solve first cost but second cost it came HO, it should take the cost from Transport-ER
as in schedule attached
If you could help me
Thanks,

Comment: @Asemomar What is your excel version? You may need `FILTER()` function which is available on `Microsoft 365`.

Comment: Dear Mr. Harun24hr
I am using excel 2019, could you please tell me how to use FILTER()

Comment: May you do not have `FILTER()` function in `Excel-2019`. Can you check to your excel just by typing to any cell.

Comment: With `FILTER()` function it will be like `=INDEX(FILTER($A$1:$A$8,$B$1:$B$8=F2,""),COUNTIF($F$2:$F2,F2))`.

Comment: No still not solved it is still repeating Grinding in both 3000 number

Comment: Can you show your formula in sheet? It must work. May you have to adjust ranges in formula based on data on sheet.

Comment: I added the formula screenshot above photo could you please check